# Set rule to allow unauthenticated users to only write new data in Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My app allows anyone to write a new message (the message cannot be updated or deleted), which should then only be visible to authenticated users. The authenticated users can edit the data (which will include things like flag as important, etc.). Think of the app like a private suggestion box (anyone can submit a suggestion but only the admins can view the submitted suggestions). I'm using the Firebase simulator and the following fails but it shouldn't:

**Firebase Simulator**

- Write
- Location: messages/
- Authenticated: false
- Data (JSON)

  {
    "key": "value"
  }

**Firebase Database Rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || auth !== null",
      },
    },
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: simulator screenshot]

Comment: The rules you shared look right at first glance: a write a `/messages` should be rejected for any non-administrative user. Can you post a screenshot of the simulator contains the same information?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added a screenshot so this question might benefit someone in the future. The answer below solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because you're testing with messages/ whereas only writes to messages/{message-id} would be allowed. Try writing to messages/somethingrandom.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I had the rules right but didn't realize I wasn't using the simulator properly.